# Add python 2.7 to ipython notebook (default python3)

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am having a really hard time adding python 2.7 as a kernel to my iphyton notebook. I have anaconda installed with a python environment called "python2." I can navigate to the environment folder and launch ipython (using python 2.7) in the script folder.

I have tried ipython kernelspec install-self using iphython.exe, however, it seems like ipython is not even a command in that window.

I tried it again in anaconda command window and it just install python3. Please help with precise steps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. I had to:

1. Change my python.exe under envs to python2.exe. I also change pythonw to pythonw2.
2. Added Anacoda\envs\python2 folder that includes python2.exe and scripts to path variable
3. Then ran this command in Anaconda command window:    `python2 -m IPython kernelspec install-self`
4. Then    `ipython kernelspec list` to verify